# symfony - Additional field in auto generated Model form

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, field

I have to 3 tables in my application. 
- `event`, `event_category` and `event_category_connection`. Which is many-to-many relation between 2 first tables. What I'm trying to do is add `sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice` with categories to `EventForm` ( which is autogenerated via Symfony - doctrine model ) that after I save event I will be able to automatically add connection between new event and already existing categories.

```
$this->widgetSchema['event_category_id'] = new sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice(array(
  'model' => 'EventCategory', 
  'add_empty' => false, 
  'multiple'=>"true",
  'expanded'=>true));
$this->setValidator('event_category_id', new sfValidatorDoctrineChoice(array(
  'model' => 'EventCategory', 
  'required' => false)));
```

This is what I added to autogenerated `EventForm`. What I understand is that during create operation new object is saved via `$form->getObject()->save()` function. This is the place where I'm getting error ( Unknown record property / related component ).

Any suggestion how can I handle this operation. This is what i'm trying to code:

In one action -> save object -> get ID of new object -> save many to many relation between categories and new object.

Krzycho.

Comment: Can you post your schema event, event_cetegory and event_category_connection?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to do a `$form->save()`, then you save your relations (this is one approach, there are probably many ways to get there):

```
  protected function processForm(sfWebRequest $request, sfForm $form)
  {
    $form->bind($request->getParameter($form->getName()), $request->getFiles($form->getName()));
    if ($form->isValid())
    {    
      $obj = $form->save();

      $this->saveRelations($request, $obj);
      // save the event_category objects in an array: $event_categories
      // $obj->EventCategory = $event_categories;
      // $obj->save();
    }
    // ...
  }
```